# jQuery Cache JSON Request

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am developing HTML5 mobile app. I want to cache particular JSON request for 10 days using jQuery. I tried setting `cache : true` on the request. But I can't specify 10 days there. Is this possible to do? Or Do I need to use HTML5 local storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just store the json data, with a date, which will enable you to look up the cached data before calling to the server for an update.

You can use the local storage api in html5.

For some ideas on how to use it you can look at this question.

[Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

To know if this will work on your target mobile devices you can look at this:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage

So, you can do this:

```
var dtDateTime = new Date();
var intDateTime = dtDateTime.getTime();
var objJSON = {};
objJSON.datetime = intDateTime;
objJSON.data = myjson;
localStorage.setItem('cachedObject', JSON.stringify(objJSON));
```

Then you can just retrieve the object and check the date and decide if you need to reload the data.

I haven't tested this, but it should be close.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `cache: true` should force the browser to follow the instructions specified in the HTTP response.  To specify caching a response for 10 days, you can add this HTTP header from the server side:  `Cache-Control: max-age=864000`.

Answer (score 0):

is it because you should use `domCache: true` according to the [doc](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-cache.html).

Comment: As I understand domCache cache pages and content. Not ajax request.